# How do I install one extension for all Firefox profiles?

Tags: macos, firefox

I run many firefox profiles simultaneously. Since moving to the mac, I've lost the British English dictionary. I can install it as an extension on each profile, but I'd like to install it once across all profiles.

I've tried `firefox -install-global-extension "/path/to/extension.xpi"` but that appears to have no effect whatsoever. I've tried copying the installed extension into various folders in `/Library` and `~/Library` but nothing has worked.

How do I install a Firefox extension once so it is active for all profiles on the computer (or this user account, either is good)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the [global extensions](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installing_extensions#Global_installation) (`.xpi` files) into the `/Applications/Firefox.app/MacOS/extensions` folder (when you select Firefox.app, right-click and "Show package contents").

If Firefox doesn't recognize the xpi, try to install it for your profile, then move it from `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<profile>.default/extensions` to the path mentioned above.

Comment: I guess this will work, but I think every upgrade to Firefox will overwrite the extensions. Is there an alternative that survives upgrades?

Comment: I think that Firefox in-application upgrades are incremental, so there is a chance that not all files in the application folder will be overwritten. I haven't tried this, though.